# Question about calculating at Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A train come to the station $X$ minuets after 9:00, $X\sim U(0,30)$.
The train stay at the station for 5 minutes and then leave.
A person reaches to the station at 9:20.
Addition:
**There was no train when the person came to the station**

**What is the probability that he didn't miss the train?**

Please help me to calculate it, and if you can, please explain me (if you understand) why the detail that that the train stay at the station is necessary?

It should be:
$$P(X<15)\;?$$

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: well, clearly this probability is 1 - probability he missed the train...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me to calculate it, and if you can, please explain me (if you understand) why the detail that that the train stay at the station is necessary?

If the train is still in the station when you arrive you can board it, and if you arrive before it arrives you can wait for it.   However, you will miss a train if you arrive after it has *left* the station.

So, what is the latest time the train can arrive and stay for 5 minutes such that it leaves before 9:20?   Then given the uniform distribution of arrival times, what is the probability of *not* missing the train?

$$P(``\text{not missed}") = P(A\in[15..30])$$

---

**Edit:** If you add a condition that no train is at the station at 9:20 then you need to find the conditional probability.  Obviously.

$$P(``\text{not missed}"\mid``\text{not there}") = P(A\in[15..30]\mid A\not\in[15..20]) \\ =\frac{P(A\in(20..30])}{P(A\in[0..15)\cup(20..30])}$$

Comment: So it's:
$$\frac{\frac13}{\frac56}=\frac25\;?$$

Answer (score 2):

Define the events 
A = the train was waiting in the station before the person came
B= the train arived after the person

then $P(A) = Pr[15 \leq X \leq 20]$ and $P(B) = Pr[20 \leq X]$

And we get that the wanted probability is $P(A)+P(B)$ as a union of disjoint events

Comment: I still don't understand why $P(A)$ is necessary, because when the person came to the station, at 9:20, **there was no train**...

Comment: Why its not: $P($The person did not miss the train$)=1-P(X<15)$?

Comment: @Yoar, (1) there was no indication that the train was not at the station when the person arrived. (2) $P(A)+P(B)=P(15\leq X\leq 20)+P(X\geq 20) = 1-P(X < 15)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, you right. but we know for sure that the train didn't came between 9:15 to 9:20, because then the person was saw the train (or I didn't understand you correctly) - so we can be sure that between 9:15 to 9:20 the train didn't come...    Or I miss somthing... Thank you!

Comment: @GrahamKemp - I add one important thing the Q - There was no trian when the person came...

Comment: @GrahamKemp - so the final answer is: $$P(X<15)=1-P(X>15)=\frac12$$??

Comment: @Yoar, No. Well, it was, but not after you altered the question.  If you *are* given such a condition you need to find the conditional probability.

Comment: @GrahamKemp - ??? I don't understand what do you mean...

Comment: Can you help me please with the answer? (@GrahamKemp.)

Comment: @Yoar IF the train is not at the station then either (a) it has not yet arrived or (b) it has already departed. Find $P(a\mid a\cup b)$

Comment: Please tell me if I'm right:
$$A=\text{The man did not miss the train} \\ B=\text{The train is not at the station at 9:20}$$
We have to calculate: $P(A|B)$, right? so. 
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$
$P(AB)=\frac13$ and $P(B)=P(0\le X \le 15)+P(20<X)=\frac56$ I'm right?
Thank you!

Comment: @Yoar $P(A) = P(15 \leq X \leq 30), P(B)=P(0\leq X\leq 15\cup 20\leq X\leq 30)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, But $P(AB)=\frac13$, I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: figure out for which values of $X$ will the condition (not missing the train) work.

For example, if the train waits 30 minutes, then the probability (not missing)
 is 1.

If it's hard to think in continuous terms, imagine that the train comes at an integer time, $0 \le i \le 30$. What happens then?